# failed fetching updates failed

Tags: updates, appcenter

```
**apt update**

E: http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease is not (yet) available (Could not connect to ppa.launchpad.net:80 (2001:67c:1560:8008::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to ppa.launchpad.net:80 (91.189.95.83), connection timed out)
E: http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu bionic InRelease is not (yet) available (Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:)
```

I checked the sources.list but couldn't find it

All of these started when i tried to install

```
$ sudo apt install software-properties-common
[sudo] password for abhar:         
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fwupd fwupd-signed fwupdate-signed libfwupd2 libido3-0.1-0 libqt5positioning5 libqt5printsupport5 libqt5qml5
  libqt5quick5 libqt5sensors5 libqt5webchannel5 libqt5webkit5 libsmbios-c2 libxmlb1 phantomjs python3-pyxattr
  rtmpdump
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  python3-software-properties
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python3-software-properties software-properties-common
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 143 kB of archives.
After this operation, 614 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Ign:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 python3-software-properties all 0.96.24.32.12+elementary17~ubuntu5.1.1
Ign:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 software-properties-common all 0.96.24.32.12+elementary17~ubuntu5.1.1
Err:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 python3-software-properties all 0.96.24.32.12+elementary17~ubuntu5.1.1
  Could not connect to ppa.launchpad.net:80 **(2001:67c:1560:8008::15)**. - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to ppa.launchpad.net:80 (91.189.95.83), connection timed out
Err:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 software-properties-common all 0.96.24.32.12+elementary17~ubuntu5.1.1
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu/pool/main/s/software-properties/python3-software-properties_0.96.24.32.12+elementary17~ubuntu5.1.1_all.deb  Could not connect to ppa.launchpad.net:80 (2001:67c:1560:8008::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to ppa.launchpad.net:80 (91.189.95.83), connection timed out
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu/pool/main/s/software-properties/software-properties-common_0.96.24.32.12+elementary17~ubuntu5.1.1_all.deb  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Answer (score 1):

There's also the /etc/apt/sources.list.d as well. Each file in that directory can contain other repositories your system will search.

Check there to see if you're referencing an outdated repo.

Comment: I did try that and removed the repo but then again when I tried to install software-properties-common or gedit I get the above error

Answer (score 1):

Now I know what was going on

The ISP company that provide my internet has as poor DNS, so I changed the DNS to 1.1.1.1 and 1.0.0.1 to modem's configuration and now everything is updating.

All my sources.list.d/ files was poiting to bionic which it's the right thing to do.

So if anyone has this problem, please try to check your DNS first

Thanks Elementary Team for this Awesome operation system that I use for my everyday work :)

Comment: Changing the DNS worked for me. Thank you!